# Passing a bash array as argv to php

Tags: php, bash

I am passing a shell script array to php file as below.

```
php file.php ${variable[@]}
```

The file.php is used to find all the permutations of the given shell script array.

```
<?php
function pc_array_power_set($array) {
    // initialize by adding the empty set
    $results = array(array( ));

    foreach ($array as $element)
        foreach ($results as $combination)
            array_push($results, array_merge(array($element), $combination));
    return $results;
}
$set = $argv;
$power_set = pc_array_power_set($set);
foreach (pc_array_power_set($set) as $combination) {
    if (2 == count($combination)) {
        print join("\t", $combination) . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

However, since I use argv as the command line argument for the php file, my output is considering the file name also as an element of the array.

**Output:**

```
echo ${variable[@]}
php checking
php file.php ${variable[@]}
```

The output is coming as,

```
php done.php
checking done.php
checking php
```

As we can see, I get the file name also in the output while I just expect the output as,

```
checking php
```

Comment: What is `php checking` doing?

Comment: Incidentally, you should probably put quotes around the bash list to avoid any odd handling of spaces: `php file.php "${variable[@]}"`. The combination of quotes and `[@]` causes each word to be quoted separately. See: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply perform an [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) on the array in your PHP script, before using it, to discard the first element:

```
$set = $argv;
array_shift($set);
$power_set = pc_array_power_set($set);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted :)